# Grid (gridlines) in Highcharts line chart

Tags: highcharts, grid, gridlines

I need to make somewhat of a grid which is dotted, like on the image here:
[image: grid in chart]

How would one go on and do about something like this? I know how to do gridlines full, but I want to have dotted gridlines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gridLineDashStyle` to make dotted gridlines:

```
xAxis: {
    gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
    gridLineWidth: 1
},
```

More style examples can be found here can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-dashstyle-all/